# Adding numbers pagination with category filter - javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination

In javascript, I have a list of items, and some items belong category 1 and others belong category 2. We have a filter to show the items of category 1 and items of category 2.

And we have previous and next buttons to navigate between items. It works fine!

So, I want to show in pagination the numbers 1, 2, 3... to navigate. Those numbers are between previous and next buttons.
Do someone have an idea?

**Demo on JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/13/

```js
        var visible = "";
    
    $('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
      visible = '.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1);
        pagination();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    
    var itemsNumber = 4;
    var min = 0;
    var max = itemsNumber;
    
    function pagination(action) {
    
        var totalItems = $("li" + visible).length;
    
        $('#next').show();
        $('#prev').show();
    
        if (max < totalItems) {//Stop action if max reaches more than total items 
            if (action == "next") {
                min = min + itemsNumber;
                max = max + itemsNumber;
            }
        }
    
        if (min > 0) {//Stop action if min reaches less than 0
            if (action == "prev") {
                min = min - itemsNumber;
                max = max - itemsNumber;
            }
        }

        if (max >= totalItems)
            $('#next').hide();        
    
        if (min <= 0)
           $('#prev').hide();
    
        $("li").hide();
        $("li" + visible).slice(min, max).show();
    }
    
    pagination();
    
    //Next
    $("#next").click(function() {
        action = "next";
        pagination(action);
    })
    
    //Previous
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        action = "prev";
        pagination(action);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="filter">
        <a href="#category-1">category 1</a>
        <a href="#category-2">category 2</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="item-wrapper">
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="category-1">item 1</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 2</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 3</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 4</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 5</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 6</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 7</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 8</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 9</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 10</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 11</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 12</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 13</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 14</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 15</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="ctrl-nav">
    <a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a><a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, what you need is to have a paging between the links, here is my approach to what you are intending to get:

```js
   var itemsNumber = 4, $items, pages = 1, current = 1;
function makePages(){
 $items = $("ul.items li:visible");
 pages = Math.ceil($items.length / itemsNumber);
 $("#pages").empty();
 for(var p=1;p<=pages;p++){
  $("#pages").append($('<a href="#">'+p+'</a>'));
 }
 showPage(1);
}
function showPage(page){
 $items.hide().slice((page - 1) * itemsNumber, page * itemsNumber).show();
 current = page;
}
makePages();
$("div.ctrl-nav").on('click', 'a', function(){
 var action = $(this).text();
 if(action == 'Previous'){
  current--;
 }else if(action == 'Next'){
  current++;
 }else if(+action > 0){
  current = +action;
 }
 if(current <= 1){
  current = 1;
 }else if(current >= pages){
  current = pages;
 }
 showPage(current);
});
$('div.filter').on('click', 'a', function(){
 var selector = $(this).attr('href').replace("#",".");
 $("ul.items li").show().not(selector).hide();
 makePages();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="filter">
        <a href="#category-1">category 1</a>
        <a href="#category-2">category 2</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="item-wrapper">
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="category-1">item 1</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 2</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 3</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 4</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 5</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 6</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 7</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 8</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 9</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 10</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 11</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 12</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 13</li>
        <li class="category-1">item 14</li>
        <li class="category-2">item 15</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="ctrl-nav">
    <a href="#">Previous</a><span id="pages"></span><a href="#">Next</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/255/)

Comment: Thank you! Very useful! I have a question: how do I do to show the current page? We have to create a class in CSS, ok? And after, what do I do?

Comment: The variable 'current' ever has the actual page, you can use it as you want or in the 'showPage' function you can add a class to the link that match with the selected page.

Comment: So I did this, but not working. $('div.ctrl-nav a').removeClass("activeUp");
 $('div.ctrl-nav #'+current).addClass("activeUp");

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to have a variable that keeps track of the page you're on and update it every time `pagination()` is called.

So when the action is '`next`', you add one to the variable, and when the action is '`prev`', you remove one.

You can add a new element between the 'next' and 'previous' buttons, and update the text to the current page whenever 'pagination()' is called.

Comment: I did a function to add the numbers. But I don't know how do to work. I've changed the div element ctrl-nav to '<ul id="pagin"></ul>'. And I did a function: 
function number_pagination()
{
 $('#pagin').html('');
 var pageCount =  $(visible).length / itemsNumber;
    
 $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a></li> ');
 for(var i = 0 ; i<pageCount;i++){
  $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a></li> ');
 }
 $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#" id="next">Next</a></li> ');
}

Comment: The numbers show correctly. But how add event click to each number? And how slice pages according clicked number? Thank you!

Comment: @Marcel You could add a class to every number, and give the 'href' attribute the value of the number itself by adding that in the 'append' funcion, and add this to your jquery:
'jQuery("class-name").click(function(){
  showList($(this.href));
});'
The showList function would than be something that shows the correct items on the page.
For that, you could take the number from the argument and multiply it by the amount of items on the page as min, and the same + items on page as max and than splice that like you did in the pagination function.